# Как выполнить LINQ запрос к БД, сравнивая 2 значения из двух разных таблиц?

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть таблица Emloyee она содержит колонку VacansyId и есть таблица Vacansies, которая содержит Name и Id. Мне нужно сравнить два значения  Emloyee.VacansyId и Vacansies.Id. Логика у меня следующая, я беру название вакансии и в таблице Vacansies ищу Id такой записи, у которой есть это имя. Затем я иду в таблицу вакансии и сравниваю этот id с VacansyId. мне нужно понять, есть ли на такой вакансии работник, то есть связаны ли они между собой. Я написал такой запрос на SQL:

```
SELECT Employees.VacansyId
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Vacansies
ON Employees.VacansyId = Vacansies.Id;
```

Но у меня Entity framework и это получается не подходит сюда. Подскажите как написать такой напрос на LINQ языке.

вот пытаюсь что-то намудрить:

```
vars = table_1.Where(x => !table_2.Contains(x)).ToList();
//db.Vacansies.Where(x => x.Id == db.Employees.Contains<Employee>(x).ToList();
List<Vacansy> voobsheVseVac = new List<Vacansy>();
voobsheVseVac.AddRange(db.Vacansies);
List<Vacansy> selectedVac = new List<Vacansy>();
foreach (var item in db.Vacansies.ToList())
{
    int OneIdFromTabl = item.Id;
    var v = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == OneIdFromTabl);
}
```

Comment: У вас уже есть контекст  и модели entity framework?

Comment: да..............

Comment: вот пытаюсь что-то намудрить:             vars = table_1.Where(x => !table_2.Contains(x)).ToList();
            //db.Vacansies.Where(x => x.Id == db.Employees.Contains<Employee>(x).ToList();

            List<Vacansy> voobsheVseVac = new List<Vacansy>();
            voobsheVseVac.AddRange(db.Vacansies);

            List<Vacansy> selectedVac = new List<Vacansy>();

            foreach (var item in db.Vacansies.ToList())
            {
                int OneIdFromTabl = item.Id;
                var v = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == OneIdFromTabl);

            }

Comment: выглядит дико мне просто нужно что-то вроде db.Vacansies.Where(x => x.Id == db.Employees.Contains<Employee>(x).ToList();

Comment: Как ваши модели выглялят? Сами классы? У вас есть внешние ключи для ваших таблиц? У вас они выражены в моделях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть примеры [Join Operations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/join-operations) прямо в документации по LINQ.

Применительно к вашей задаче:

```cs
var report = from vacancy in db.Vacancies
             join employee in db.Employees on vacancy.Id equals employee.VacancyId into g
             select new { vacancy.Name, HasEmployees = g.Any() };
```